# How to prove that a function is quasiconcave?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

I would like to check if the function $$f(x, y)=-3 x y^{2}-x^{2} y+2 x y,(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$$ is quasiconcave. I would use the following proposition that I have found searching on Google, but I am not convinced that it is possible to use such a method:

Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined from $A$, a nonempty, convex set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, into $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that (1) $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, (2) $f$ is strictly increasing in each component $\left(f_{1} \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}>0, f_{2} \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}\right.$ on $\left.A\right)$. 1. If $f$ is quasiconcave, then the determinant of the bordered Hessian is non-negative the bordered Hessian: $B_{2} \equiv\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & f_{1} & f_{2} \\ f_{1} & f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{2} & f_{21} & f_{22}\end{array}\right]$
that is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&2 f_{1}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) f_{2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) f_{12}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)-\left[f_{1}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)\right]^{2} f_{22}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)-\left[f_{2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)\right]^{2} f_{11}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \geq 0 \\
&\forall\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \in A
\end{aligned}
$$
2. If
$$
2 f_{1}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) f_{2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) f_{12}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)-\left[f_{1}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)\right]^{2} f_{22}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)-\left[f_{2}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)\right]^{2} f_{11}\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)>0
$$
$\forall\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \in A$, then $f$ is strictly quasiconcave.

The determinant of the Hessian is equal to $ -\frac{2y^2}{e^{2x}}$, which is non-negative. Therefore, can I say that this function is not quasiconcave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mateus Maciel, take a look in this other question:

[Quasi-concavity of a function of two variables such as $z=(x^a + y^b)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843350/quasi-concavity-of-a-function-of-two-variables-such-as-z-xa-yb2)

f is quasiconcave iff the upper level sets are convex. Indeed you can use the bordered hessian. But in this case is faster if you use the concept of upper level set.

Comment: Thanks, @Fernanda!